# Distinct List Elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharpkml

I have a list collection of following type

```
CoordinateCollection pointCoordinates = new CoordinateCollection();
```

it adds up list of type vector.
I want to remove duplicate entries from the list

I am trying like this

```
pointCoordinates = pointCoordinates.Distinct();
```

it gives me an error

```
cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.generic.ienumerable<SharpKML.Base.Vector> to SharpKML.Dom.CoordinateCollection
```

Please help me in solving this. I want unique set of records

Comment: is the error caused when you distinct or assign

Comment: Read the error message again. I think it is clear enough. Use another variable to assign the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since  `CoordinateCollection` implements `ICollection<Vector>` and `Vector` overrides `Equals` + `GethashCode` you can use `Distinct`. But you need to use the constructor of `CoordinateCollection` to create a new:

```
pointCoordinates = new CoordinateCollection(pointCoordinates.Distinct());
```

Note that i'm not familiar with `SharpKML`, i have looked at it's [source code](https://sharpkml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SharpKml/Dom/Fields/CoordinateCollection.cs).

Comment: Thanks Tim Schmelter.

Answer (score 1):

As the message states, you can't implicitly assign an object of type `system.collections.generic.ienumerable<SharpKML.Base.Vector>` to an object of type `SharpKML.Dom.CoordinateCollection`.  I would suggest using one of their type conversion methods (documented [here](http://sharpkml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SharpKml/Dom/Fields/CoordinateCollection.cs)).

Answer (score 0):

Distinct is going to return an `IEnumerable<SharpKML.Base.Vector>`. You can't assign that type to your `CoordinateCollection` instance because even though is is an `IEnumerable<SharpKML.Base.Vector>` it may not also be an instance of `CoordinateCollection`.

If you need an instance of `CoordinateCollection` create/use a constructor that will take an `IEnumerable<SharpKML.Base.Vector>` as input otherwise if an `IEnumerable<SharpKML.Base.Vector>` will do then declare your variable as such.